# Validate rows under a column in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Good day.

I am making a program that imports excel files that can validate rows under a column.

For the KPI COLUMN, [(image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojwrI.png) I must validate all rows under it.
The only valid KPI Items are:

**Revenue**

**Sales Volume**

**Gross Con**

**Brand Con.**

If the KPI items are valid, a text file would be open
and indicate if it is valid.

For *example*.

Revenue - *is valid*   // **since it is existing and valid.**

Gross Con - is valid // **likewise above.**

**SAMPLE** - is ***NOT*** valid because it is not included for the valid KPI names.

How do I programmatically do this as I do not know how to select the rows under KPI Items?

Here is my sample code:

```
 public void Validate_KPI(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\brandon\InvalidKPI.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        decimal num;
        if (dataGridView.ColumnCount > 2)
        {
            for (int h = 2; h < dataGridView.ColumnCount; h++)
            {
               for (int i = 0; i <dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
               {
                  if (!Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString(), out num))
                  {
                      if (dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "Revenue" || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "Sales Volume" || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "Gross Con" || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "Brand Con")
                      {
                          sb.AppendLine(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + " is Valid");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          //MessageBox.Show("Row not decimal:" + " [ " + dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + "] in column "  + dataGridView.Columns[h].Name);
                          sb.AppendLine(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + " is not valid.");
                      }
                  }
               }
            }
        }

        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        Process.Start(@"C:\brandon\InvalidKPI.txt");

        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

    }
```

Here are the [results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6dyi.png)

I just want to **LIMIT** the row selection just under KPI COLUMN only not the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I did it.

```
 public void Validate_KPI(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\brandon\InvalidKPI.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        decimal num;
        if (dataGridView.ColumnCount > 2)
        {
            int h = 2;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString(), out num))
                    {
                        if (dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "Revenue" || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "Sales Volume" || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "Gross Con" || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "Brand Con")
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + " is Valid");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show("Row not decimal:" + " [ " + dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + "] in column "  + dataGridView.Columns[h].Name);
                            sb.AppendLine(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + " is not valid.");
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        Process.Start(@"C:\brandon\InvalidKPI.txt");

        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

    }
```